# Play audio without buffer

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I am playing an audio file in my iphone app,I fetch the audio from a url.While playing it stops for a while to buffer.
How can I make playing audio without any buffer or play after loaded fully ?

```
  -(void) playAudio2
    {

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:domain/iphonetest/mp3/sol.mp3"];

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    [audioPlayer  setVolume:1];


     [audioPlayer  play];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSURLConnection or AFNetworkingKit to download the file (There is lots of resources show how to download a file. Just search for it).

Then in the `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` delegate method for NSURLConnection or in the completionBlock for AFNetworkingKit, play the file like your code. But use `NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sound_file]` for initializing url and use `[audioPlayer prepareToPlay]` before playing that.